# dynamodb update one without key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

My app has a table of tickets. The tickets have various properties, such as client, status (new, open, closed, etc), date created, date updated.

My agents need to grab a single ticket from this db to work on using certain criteria (such as the client id = a, the status is open or closed) and with certain order of priority (such as oldest tickets first, or tickets with status new first, etc).

Ideally, an agent gets a ticket by first claiming one that fits the criteria (using an update that sets the field active_agent), and then grabs it.

I've recently started working with DynamoDb to see if it can be the solution for us, but I've run into a wall trying to get this situation to work. I can't seem to (a) update a ticket with a set of parameters like this, and (b) order the tickets I grab through query or scan (where I could limit it to 1 that fits my criteria).

Any guidance would me much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Use Update Expressions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html

b) Query results are always sorted by the sort key value. If the data type of the sort key is Number, the results are returned in numeric order; otherwise, the results are returned in order of UTF-8 bytes. By default, the sort order is ascending. To reverse the order, set the ScanIndexForward parameter to false.
You can also use Limit for the number of items returned: The maximum number of items to evaluate (not necessarily the number of matching items). If DynamoDB processes the number of items up to the limit while processing the results, it stops the operation and returns the matching values up to that point, and a key in LastEvaluatedKey to apply in a subsequent operation, so that you can pick up where you left off. Also, if the processed data set size exceeds 1 MB before DynamoDB reaches this limit, it stops the operation and returns the matching values up to the limit, and a key in LastEvaluatedKey to apply in a subsequent operation to continue the operation.

More info at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html